# Cron job in hostserver not working

Tags: python, ubuntu, terminal, cron, cron-task

I have a python program which extracts data and saves it in the database

I am using cron tab on my local computer as follows which works fine!

```
15 20 * * * python /home/ahmed/Dropbox/AppFlatForRent.py
```

Now i am using a similar command on my hostserver but it doesnt work

```
15 20 * * * python /home/AppFlatForRent.py
```

[image: Left: Local computer, Right hostserver]

I have also tried this but doesnt work

```
/usr/bin/python /home/AppFlatForRent.py
```

When I run the `python /home/AppFlatForRent.py` independently, it works perfectly (since i am getting values in the host's database)

What is wrong with the cronjob command?

Comment: type `pgrep cron` and see if cron process is running. see the `/var/log/syslog` of your hostserver. you will find cron process is runnign or not.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a problem with the permissions. Make a copy of the file in the /tmp directory and run the cron:

```
15 20 * * * python /tmp/AppFlatForRent.py
```

if it works, you will know where is the problem, otherwise cron is not running.

Comment: i fixed it out. the problem was that in the server the timezone was different which i just fixed